# Anyone know where i can get MSBuild Community Tasks for dotnet 2.0? or

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity-5.0

Can someone offer me some advice on TeamCity+CI+Deployment

So far my "it feels rubbish" solution is;

TeamCity + three build configs;
  1) solution runner (outputs all installer pre-reqs)
  2) command line runner +"Version Controlled Build" updates version numbers (only on 1 success)
  3) command line runner \devenv.exe to builder installer msi (only on 2 success)
  4) Zip up my msi+pre-req output folders
  5) FTP to remote ftp location

ive got the first three parts working ok and itll do, but i cant for the life of me figure out how to automatically zip it up and ftp it to a site.

ive looked at msbuild + MSBuild Community Tasks but thats not working with 2.0 and the site says its 3.5+ (probably why) could i install 3.5? would that do anything odd with the build? i.e. can i install 3.5 to get build tasks working. but using 3.5 msbuild tell it to compile using the 2.0 compiler? is that even possible? ive no idea

if it comes to it i'll write a damn batch file but id rather not. Anyone got any ideas on how this should be done because this just feels wrong to me... i might be new but still somethings not right here....?

using vb.net 2.0 in vs2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always point msbuild to use .Net 2.0 - it should be backward compatible. Besides, you're compiling A PROJECT which has it's own settings and there you can tell the compiler which framework it need to use.